# Error Message "Class Not Registered" when dropping new component onto form

Tags: delphi, components, activex, ocx

Using Windows XP running Delphi 2010.

I have been provided with a third party package called CsdEft.ocx (for interfacing to EFTPOS terminals)

*To install I did the following:*

- Select "Import Component"
- Select "Import ActiveX Control"
- Select "Add" then select CsdEft.ocx. The selected OCX is displayed. Click Next.

  Shows dialog:

  > Class Name:  `TCscEFT`
  >
  > Pallet Page: `ActiveX`
  >
  > Unit Dir Name: `C:\Delphi\Components`
  >
  > Search Path: `$(BDS)\lib;$(BDSUSERDIR)...................`
  >
  > Generate Component Wrappers - Checked
- Click Next.
- Select "Install into New Package"
- Enter EFTPOS as the package name.
- Click Finish.

  Dialog shows:

  > Package C:\Documents and Settings.............\EFTPOS1.bpl has been installed. The following component(s) have been registered: TCsdEft.

OK . All looks fine.

I can see the component in the ActiveX page in the Component Pallet.

BUT when I try to select the component and drop it on a form I get "Class Not Registered" error.

Hopefully someone can give me some pointer to what is wrong here.

Comment: As an alternative to registering the COM server you could use registration free COM

Answer (score 15):

Sounds like the OCX itself is not registered with Windows using the command-line `regsvr32.exe` tool.  You imported the OCX file directly, so the IDE created a component wrapper based on the OCX's embedded TypeLibrary, but the wrapper is going to try to instantiate the ActiveX object via `CoCreateInstance()`, so you will get a "Class not registered" error if `CoCreateInstance()` cannot find the OCX.